# Facebook Pixel ViewContent Issue

Tags: facebook

having issues implementing Facebook Pixel ViewContent event into a website.

Looked everywhere online for answers but nothing is coming up and I have found websites using the same Event, and they use it the same way I do.

I'm basically getting the following error within my Facebook Business account:

> Missing content_type parameter from "ViewContent" in James Glen Car Sales's Pixel

However the following code is on the website:

```
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
    content_type: 'vehicle',
    content_ids: ['1431445']
});
```

which is what all guides recommend.

Here a link to the page which is having the issue:
https://www.jamesglen.co.uk/used-audi-a4-airdrie-lanarkshire-1431445

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your website and it appears that you are using content_type wrong.

You can only use "product" or "product_group" in the content_type field.

You can read more information here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/dynamic-product-ads/product-audiences/v2.8/#content_type